# Is it possible to create CRUD child view sections using .netcore MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, view, crud, asp.net-core-2.0

I am very new to this and have been developing a simple crud application as I follow the Microsoft docs tutorial for Data Access - MVC with EF Core. The tutorial is very good but as ideas have developed in my head I need a little more support to move forward.

My CRUD application is very simple I have 2 related entities Person and ContactDetails I am using a third entity ContactAssignments as a navigation property which contains its own ID field the PersonID and the ContactDetailsID so a single Person can have many contact details.

I am able to show the multiple contact details related to the person in the /person/details/# view if I have the details already seeded in the database. The next step is to be able to update and delete the ContactDetails from the Persons create and Edit views and controllers.

As I am new to this I am not sure how to create a "child" section on the Persons Create and Edit views to provide CRUD interface for ContactDetails. Ideally I would like to to have the create and Edit views for contactDetails as a child part on the same page of /person/create/ or /person/edit/# instead of visiting /contactdetails/create or /contactdetails/Edit/#

I appreciate the "child" aspect may not be possible but if not then some alternative suggestions would be welcome.

I hope this question is clear and i appreciate any assistance and pointers.

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 0):

it's possible if you save or edit the whole object like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ContactDetails Details { get; set; }
}
```

If you're planning only one object of contacts you should just add it in the same object. It will be better for performance if you will have a lot of rows in database in two tables and you'll need to join them.

But I'd advice you to separate client(UI) and server(database) services and read about RESTful approaches in the future.

I hope it'll help you.